# Set affinity for started process with windows bash (and use same terminal window)

Tags: windows, bash, affinity, msys2

I open MSYS2 bash to start another app (ruby for example).
Then I can use Process Explorer or Task Manager to set the affinity for ruby process.

Is it possible to set it directly from bash when executing said ruby.exe, and use the current terminal window (therefore I think windows builtin `start` command will not suffice)? I am thinking of something like `bash --affinity=1 -c ruby.exe`.

When I do a basic run from bash, the process tree looks like in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Why work from MSYS2 and not directly from Windows?

Comment: Can I do such a thing easier there? I guess I like bash.

Comment: Its integration with Windows API isn't good. You would be calling Windows executables, after all.